# i scam ico hacker please help

Tags: ico

I have remitted Etherium to the hacker's address. Can I get a refund? please help
hash 0x39ab06640a6fa38ccb3a94e94b38254d5f4a16bce2ee98eb3d692d893a3721d6
anyone can i help?
my ethwallet
0x948D2dE4d0554Ad40aAF7B4150894213f6845335 
and hacker wallet 
0x39ab06640a6fa38ccb3a94e94b38254d5f4a16bce2ee98eb3d692d893a3721d6
sir
my 10.5 eth just steeling
please help

Comment: Unfortunately transaction in the blockchain are final and cannot be reversed without significant effort (ie 51% attack or a fork).

Comment: The address in question sent the funds to binance, perhaps if they haven't withdrawn it yet binance can help you. Or if you get authorities involved you could get binance to reveal the information of the person. But on the other hand the person who cashed out didn't necessarily do something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck. The transaction has been [mined](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x39ab06640a6fa38ccb3a94e94b38254d5f4a16bce2ee98eb3d692d893a3721d6) and included into the blockchain. It's irreversible at this point.

Always double check addresses before sending ETH.